# VBA - Application.EnableEvents = True always sets it to False in Function Call

Tags: excel, vba

I need to regularly disable/enable settings in a macro often, and the function I have is not working as expected. Running Application.EnableEvents = True always sets it to False.

This is my function.

```
Sub DisableSettings(setting As Boolean)


    If (setting = True) Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual   
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False   
        Application.EnableEvents = False   
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Else
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic   
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True   
        Application.EnableEvents = True  
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End If
End Sub
```

I've walked through the debugger/used the immediate window many times trying to figure this out - whenever Application.EnableEvents = True is run, it gets set to False. Regardless of the state of Application.Events immediately before I run that line. It works just fine if I run it in the immediate window.

Eg. In the immediate window, if ?Application.EnableEvents returns False and I run Application.EnableEvents = True and then run ?Application.EnableEvents, True is returned as expected. Yet, if I check ?Application.EnableEvents after each line in the macro run with F8, it'll be True for every line until it changes to False with Application.EnableEvents = True

I'll mention too that my workbook has a number of Worksheet_Change events in it, and those events call this function. Mentioning this simply because many other similar questions involve Worksheet_Change events. For testing purposes, I attached this macro to a button on a sheet with no event handlers on it.

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print setting, Application.EnableEvents` at the end of the subroutine, what is the result in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Can't see any problems trying to replicate what you describe.